# Помогите написать firestore rule

Tags: firebase, firestore

Мне нужно написать rule, где я буду искать юзера организации

Мой код

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function authUserKey(organizationKey){
      (/databases/$(database).collection("users").where("organizationKey", "==", $(organizationKey)).get())
        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                return doc.key
            });
        });
    }
```